Explaining adabatic transportation of an electron in terms of the quantum Hamiltonian
In several text I read, it is assumed that when transporting and electron along a curve $C$ in magnetic field, (the quantum Hamiltonian of the electron is $H=(p-qA)^2/(2m) + qV$) the wavefunction picks up a phase $\int_C A\cdot dx.$
I struggle to understand what is really going on, because to transport the electron along the curve, we need to somehow "apply external force" to move it. In QM this is done by slowly varying time-dependent Hamiltonians. Then we can compute the Berry phase. But $H$ and $x$ do not commute, and we do not have simultaneous eigenstates of $H,x$. So how does Berry phase make sense here?
What's more perplexing is that an electron in an eigenstate of $H$ does not have fixed position, so how could statements like "the electron is transported along a curve" even make sense?
